# qemu-system-aarch64: -spice: invalid option

Tags: qemu

This is my code(Imported from UTM, which is broken):

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -L /Users/brandon/Applications/UTM.app/Contents/Resources/qemu -S -spice "unix=on,addr=/Users/---/Library/Group Containers/WDNLXAD4W8.com.utmapp.UTM/0F075A81-8EDB-4245-B17D-061AA68FD704.spice,disable-ticketing=on,image-compression=off,playback-compression=off,streaming-video=off,gl=on" -chardev spiceport,id=org.qemu.monitor.qmp,name=org.qemu.monitor.qmp.0 -mon chardev=org.qemu.monitor.qmp,mode=control -nodefaults -vga none -device virtio-net-pci,mac=AE:AF:A6:1C:D7:8B,netdev=net0 -netdev vmnet-shared,id=net0 -device virtio-gpu-gl-pci -cpu host -smp cpus=8,sockets=1,cores=8,threads=1 -machine virt -accel hvf -drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,file=/Users/---/Applications/UTM.app/Contents/Resources/qemu/edk2-aarch64-code.fd,readonly=on -drive "if=pflash,unit=1,file=/Users/---/Library/Containers/com.utmapp.UTM/Data/Documents/Windows 11.utm/Data/efi_vars.fd" -m 8192 -device ich9-intel-hda -device hda-duplex -device nec-usb-xhci,id=usb-bus -device usb-tablet,bus=usb-bus.0 -device usb-mouse,bus=usb-bus.0 -device usb-kbd,bus=usb-bus.0 -device qemu-xhci,id=usb-controller-0 -chardev spicevmc,name=usbredir,id=usbredirchardev0 -device usb-redir,chardev=usbredirchardev0,id=usbredirdev0,bus=usb-controller-0.0 -chardev spicevmc,name=usbredir,id=usbredirchardev1 -device usb-redir,chardev=usbredirchardev1,id=usbredirdev1,bus=usb-controller-0.0 -chardev spicevmc,name=usbredir,id=usbredirchardev2 -device usb-redir,chardev=usbredirchardev2,id=usbredirdev2,bus=usb-controller-0.0 -device usb-storage,drive=driveD7009BCF-2F84-4263-A943-3D3172E42D37,removable=true,bootindex=0,bus=usb-bus.0 -drive if=none,media=cdrom,id=driveD7009BCF-2F84-4263-A943-3D3172E42D37 -device nvme,drive=drive30D3D5C5-0482-4FF1-AF8B-3EC71F330561,serial=30D3D5C5-0482-4FF1-AF8B-3EC71F330561,bootindex=1 -drive "if=none,media=disk,id=drive30D3D5C5-0482-4FF1-AF8B-3EC71F330561,file=/Users/brandon/Library/Containers/com.utmapp.UTM/Data/Documents/Windows 11.utm/Data/30D3D5C5-0482-4FF1-AF8B-3EC71F330561.qcow2,discard=unmap,detect-zeroes=unmap" -device usb-storage,drive=drive72383F72-3B29-4849-B30A-43C8593DEFD3,removable=true,bootindex=2,bus=usb-bus.0 -drive if=none,media=cdrom,id=drive72383F72-3B29-4849-B30A-43C8593DEFD3 -device virtio-serial -device virtserialport,chardev=vdagent,name=com.redhat.spice.0 -chardev spicevmc,id=vdagent,debug=0,name=vdagent -device virtserialport,chardev=charchannel1,id=channel1,name=org.spice-space.webdav.0 -chardev spiceport,name=org.spice-space.webdav.0,id=charchannel1 -name "Windows 11" -uuid 0F075A81-8EDB-4245-B17D-061AA68FD704 -rtc base=localtime -device virtio-rng-pci
```

The error says -spice: invalid option.

I tried reinstalling qemu. I expected the VM to boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that when the QEMU binary was built the necessary dependencies for SPICE weren't present, so configure disabled it (it is an optional feature). If you pass configure the option `--enable-spice` then that will force configure to either enable this feature or else to exit with an error, so you can identify what dependent libraries you need to install.